# Spark dataframe withColumn on partitions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

A column "colA" in a dataframe contains integer values:

```
+-----+
| colA|
+-----+
|    1|
|    2|
|    1|
|    3|
+-----+
```

These integer values can be mapped to strings through a Redis dictionary:

```
+----+------+
| key| value|
+----+------+
|   1|     a|
|   2|     b|
|   3|     c|
+----+------+
```

I need to create a new column "colB" which will contain the mapping of "colA" to string values as such:

```
+-----+-----+
| colA| colB|
+-----+-----+
|    1|    a|
|    2|    b|
|    1|    a|
|    3|    c|
+-----+-----+
```

My goal is to make batch requests to Redis, in order to avoid the latency of a single Redis request per row.

In Spark Core API (i.e. RDDs), I could do this, by using the mapPartitions function. Is there any way of achieving the same, by using the Spark SQL API?

Note that I want to avoid the overhead of:

- converting the dataframe to RDD and vice versa.
- the associated encoder by calling mapPartitions directly on the
  dataframe.

Comment: there is mapPartition function with dataframe as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note that I want to avoid the overhead of:
>
> - ...
> - the associated encoder by calling mapPartitions directly on the dataframe.

This actually makes it impossible. Any operation which doesn't use SQL DSL, requires decoding to external type and encoding back to internal type. With primitive values it is low cost operation, if binary encoder is used, but it still requires `Encoder`.

Comment: Thank's. I'll take this for the correct answer. Can you please refer to examples for using a binary encoder?

Comment: "Binary" `Encoders` are used any time where you return `Product` types, like tuples `(Int, String, Long)`. It is in opposite to `RowEncoder` which has to be use when you return `Row`.